# GO with Heroku Deployments

Tags: go, heroku

Hello i am currently running into a problem with using Heroku! It finds all my dependency's until

```
build project: cannot load io/fs: cannot find module providing package io/fs
```

I have the vendor directory on my github repo but it just wont build?

Comment: You are probably using an outdated version of go.

Comment: Also note that if you did vendor everything your project should continue to build, which means you are missing dependencies. You should be using modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On heroku -> your project -> Settings -> Buildpacks, and add 'heroku/go'.

Then execute in any terminal:

> heroku config:set GOVERSION=1.16